# Is personal produce counted in GDP?

Tags: gdp

Good day. And sorry if it's a stupid question.

I came across a question on another q&a site earlier today. It was about a hypothetical scenario. The question was if everyone in a nation becomes self-sufficient, would GDP increase. There were answers where the answerers opined that it might actually reduce the GDP. Others had the opposite opinion.

I studied a bit about it and thought any product is counted in GDP. Am I correct?

Would personal produce (consumed by own) be counted in GDP calculation?

Comment: By personal produce did you mean, for example, the lettuce or tomato one grows in her own garden for personal consumption and not for sale?

Comment: Thanks for the comment Herr K. Yes, I mean just that. Also service can be included. Say, washing my own car instead of hiring someone to do it. Do check a [related question](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/39783/what-is-it-called-when-there-is-no-personal-increase-of-wealth-but-gdp-increases) which is opposite to the scenario described here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is often called “home production.” By default, the answer is no, but different countries have different methodologies.

This US Bureau of Economic Analysis page has some information: [BEA webpage.](https://www.bea.gov/data/special-topics/household-production)

They produce a “satellite account” that includes this information. (Not officially part of GDP, but official supplemental information.)

Comment: Thank you Brian Romanchuk for your answer. It includes interesting information. I will go through it.

Comment: I had totally missed the "final goods" part in GDP's definition. Looking it again, I got it.